# How to find IP address of Postman?

Tags: postman

Whenever we are hitting some secured api's, at that time we face some issue like Forbidden request... basically because of security reason we can't hit api. To resolve this Problem we have to whitelist our ip address. Now Question is that how to find Postman IP address.

Previously I done this with another way, right now I have solution for this.

Comment: Postman doesn't have IP address, search _what is my ip_ in google and whitelist that.

Answer (score 2):

Send request to https://httpbin.org/ip it responds with ip. Use that ip to whitelist.